# Deleting all records in a msaccess table

Tags: c#, ms-access

is it possible to delete all the records in a MSaccess table using  c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  This page has examples for connecting to an access DB and then just use a DELETE command.

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_dbconnection.asp

Comment: @Winston Smith: does MS Access support TRUNCATE?

Comment: My understanding is that the Jet/ACE database engine executes "DELETE * FROM table" as a truncate, i.e., replaces the old table with an empty duplicate. I just ran ?CurrentDB.Execute "DELETE * FROM tblGBTest" on a table with 7,148,975 records and the results were instantaneous.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "DELETE * FROM..." -- that's a weird construct. Why not the standard "DELETE FROM..." Does adding an asterisk make it perform better?

Answer (score -3):

Access is a little weird because it is **DAO** at its core.

- Truncate works in SQL server
- Normally in most flavors of SQL database

**Delete** From **TableX** where `DummyField='YYY'`

In **Access** it is something like:

```
  `Delete * From TableX where DummyField='YYY'`
```

I just recently am looking at **Access**, I can't wait to get to
**"Real"** Database programming. Access is very capable it just 
 doesn't scale well and can cause data to be scattered around
 on companies workstations.

Comment: -1 A reference to a "dummy field" is unnecessary, and the editorial content in this "answer" adds nothing useful to the discussion.